# Change javascript so it works for numerous variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code below... It takes a search field, and quickly searches the table for matching items, and hides all the other results. Right now this code works for a single search field (with class .search), and a single table (with id #SearchableTbl).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.search').on('keyup',function(){
        var searchTerm = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $('#SearchableTbl tbody tr').each(function(){
            var lineStr = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
            if(lineStr.indexOf(searchTerm) === -1){
                $(this).hide();
            }else{
                $(this).show();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I don't know javascript, so I'm not sure how to make this function work for multiple tables. So, if the first search field was .search1 (and not just .search), and the second was .search2.  And, the tables being searched were #SearchableTbl1 and #SearchableTbl2 (respectively).

Can someone help me modify the code so this works with many (not just 2) tables?  As I said, I don't know javascript (but I do know a little PHP), so I'm trying to do something like this (below is a mish-mash of PHP and Javascript, which definitely wont work, but should get my point across) ....

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 for($var=1; $var<10; $var++;) {  
   $('.search($var)').on('keyup',function(){
        var searchTerm = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $('#SearchableTbl($var) tbody tr').each(function(){
            var lineStr = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
            if(lineStr.indexOf(searchTerm) === -1){
                $(this).hide();
            }else{
                $(this).show();
            }
        });
    });
  }
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jQuery it depends on your dom structure, so wrap the table and search input (or anything else for that "data table" component) in a div, then the simple fact you're inputting into a specific input you can use that to find the parent element then `find()` the table.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.data-table input').on('keyup',function(){
       // find the parent
       var parent = $(this).closest('.data-table')

        var searchTerm = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

        $(parent).find('table tbody tr').each(function(){
            var lineStr = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
            if(lineStr.indexOf(searchTerm) === -1){
                $(this).hide();
            }else{
                $(this).show();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```
<div class="data-table">
  <input type="text"/>

  <table>
   ...
  <table>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome. Had to do some tweaking to get it to work (since the search field was in one table, and the results table was another), but it works now. Thanks alot!